# Recieving data on Android app from imu and after displaying save in .csv file

Tags: android, csv, android-studio

As I am receiving data from  imu razor 9 degree of freedom,(giving me the value of accelerometer,gyro,and magnetometer) we can burn code in it with the help of Arduino IDE.
So, currently I am receiving data on my Android app as shown in image is like that and in my Android code I am updating receiving code here private void: **updateReceivedData(byte[] data)**
So when I append data to show my values it works fine like that: **mDumpTextView.append(message);**
But according to requirement, I want that data in array so I can easily display that specific value on screen, not the whole data and at the same time. I need data to store in .csv file . but I am not able to do this . When I use to save in arraym it doesn't work for me: [data obtain from imu in an append form in Android app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lmxfF.png)

The whole code is available on GitHub: 
 
https://github.com/mik3y/usb-serial-for-android/tree/master/usbSerialExamples/src/main

But in the code:

```
public class SerialConsoleActivity extends Activity {

private final String TAG = SerialConsoleActivity.class.getSimpleName();

/**
 * Driver instance, passed in statically via
 * {@link #show(Context, UsbSerialPort)}.
 *
 * <p/>
 * This is a devious hack; it'd be cleaner to re-create the driver using
 * arguments passed in with the {@link #startActivity(Intent)} intent. We
 * can get away with it because both activities will run in the same
 * process, and this is a simple demo.
 */
private static UsbSerialPort sPort = null;

private TextView mTitleTextView;
private TextView mDumpTextView;
private ScrollView mScrollView;
private CheckBox chkDTR;
private CheckBox chkRTS;

private final ExecutorService mExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

private SerialInputOutputManager mSerialIoManager;

private final SerialInputOutputManager.Listener mListener =
        new SerialInputOutputManager.Listener() {

    @Override
    public void onRunError(Exception e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Runner stopped.");
    }

    @Override
    public void onNewData(final byte[] data) {
        SerialConsoleActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                SerialConsoleActivity.this.updateReceivedData(data);
            }
        });
    }
};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.serial_console);
   // mDumpTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.consoleText);
    mTitleTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.demoTitle);
    mDumpTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.consoleText);
   // mDumpTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ex);

    mScrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.demoScroller);
    chkDTR = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBoxDTR);
    chkRTS = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBoxRTS);

    chkDTR.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            try {
                sPort.setDTR(isChecked);
            }catch (IOException x){}
        }
    });

    chkRTS.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            try {
                sPort.setRTS(isChecked);
            }catch (IOException x){}
        }
    });

}


@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    stopIoManager();
    if (sPort != null) {
        try {
            sPort.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Ignore.
        }
        sPort = null;
    }
    finish();
}

void showStatus(TextView theTextView, String theLabel, boolean theValue){
    String msg = theLabel + ": " + (theValue ? "enabled" : "disabled") + "\n";
    theTextView.append(msg);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Log.d(TAG, "Resumed, port=" + sPort);
    if (sPort == null) {
        mTitleTextView.setText("No serial device.");
    } else {
        final UsbManager usbManager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);

        UsbDeviceConnection connection = usbManager.openDevice(sPort.getDriver().getDevice());
        if (connection == null) {
            mTitleTextView.setText("Opening device failed");
            return;
        }

        try {
            sPort.open(connection);
            sPort.setParameters(57600, 8, UsbSerialPort.STOPBITS_1, UsbSerialPort.PARITY_NONE);

            showStatus(mDumpTextView, "CD  - Carrier Detect", sPort.getCD());
           // sPort.getCD();
            showStatus(mDumpTextView, "CTS - Clear To Send", sPort.getCTS());
            //sPort.getCTS();
            showStatus(mDumpTextView, "DSR - Data Set Ready", sPort.getDSR());
            //sPort.getDSR();
            showStatus(mDumpTextView, "DTR - Data Terminal Ready", sPort.getDTR());
            //sPort.getDTR();
            showStatus(mDumpTextView, "DSR - Data Set Ready", sPort.getDSR());
            //sPort.getDSR();
            showStatus(mDumpTextView, "RI  - Ring Indicator", sPort.getRI());
            //sPort.getRI();
           showStatus(mDumpTextView, "RTS - Request To Send", sPort.getRTS());
            //sPort.getRTS();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error setting up device: " + e.getMessage(), e);
            mTitleTextView.setText("Error opening device: " + e.getMessage());
            try {
                sPort.close();
            } catch (IOException e2) {
                // Ignore.
            }
            sPort = null;
            return;
        }
        mTitleTextView.setText("Serial device: " + sPort.getClass().getSimpleName());
    }
    onDeviceStateChange();
}

private void stopIoManager() {
    if (mSerialIoManager != null) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Stopping io manager ..");
        mSerialIoManager.stop();
        mSerialIoManager = null;
    }
}
public void writeToCsv1(String x,String y,String z) throws IOException {

    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/project");
    boolean success = true;
    if (!folder.exists()) {
        success = folder.mkdir();
    }
    if (success) {
        // Do something on success
        String csv = folder + "/AccelerometerValue1.csv";
        FileWriter file_writer = new FileWriter(csv, true);
        ;


        String s = c.get(Calendar.YEAR) + "," + c.get(Calendar.MONTH) + "," + c.get(Calendar.DATE) + "," + c.get(Calendar.HOUR) + "," + c.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + "," + c.get(Calendar.SECOND) + "," + c.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND) + "," + x + "," + y + "," + z + "\n";

        file_writer.append(s);
        file_writer.close();

    }
}

private void startIoManager() {
    if (sPort != null) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Starting io manager ..");
        mSerialIoManager = new SerialInputOutputManager(sPort, mListener);
        mExecutor.submit(mSerialIoManager);
    }
}
private String convert(byte[] data) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(data.length);
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; ++ i) {
        if (data[i] < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        sb.append((char) data[i]);
    }
    return sb.toString();




}
private void onDeviceStateChange() {
    stopIoManager();
    startIoManager();
}

private void updateReceivedData(byte[] data) { 
final String message = convert(data);



if (convert(data) =="A") {


        mDumpTextView.append("\n\n");
}



  mDumpTextView.append(message);



   mScrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, mDumpTextView.getBottom());
}

/**
 * Starts the activity, using the supplied driver instance.
 *
 * @param context
 * @param driver
 */
static void show(Context context, UsbSerialPort port) {
    sPort = port;
    final Intent intent = new Intent(context, SerialConsoleActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP |     Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
    context.startActivity(intent);
}
[enter image description here][1]}
```